# SQL error when trying to create a tabel and populate it

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this SQL error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `tsv` (`Id`,`Date`,`Quantity`) VALUES( `1`,`2009-07-01`,`174`, `1`,`' at line 9
```

I'm not really experienced in SQL queries and i really can´t see whats wrong here... I tried replacing "`" with "'". And also removing "ENGINE=MyISAM" as I'm not sure thats the engine I'm using.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tsv` 
( `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`Id` text NOT NULL, `Date` text NOT NULL, 
`Quantity` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`_id`) ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=68 ; 
INSERT INTO `tsv` (`Id`,`Date`,`Quantity`) 
VALUES( `1`,`2009-07-01`,`174`, `1`,`2009-07-02`,`96`, 
`1`,`2009-07-03`,`271`, `1`,`2009-07-04`,`335`, `1`,
`2009-07-06`,`72`, `1`,`2009-07-07`,`246`, `1`,`2009-07-08`,
`93`, `1`,`2009-07-09`,`191`, `1`,`2009-07-10`,`136`, `1`,
`2009-07-11`,`200`, `1`,`2009-07-13`,`151`, `1`,`2009-07-15`,`99`);
```

And the PHP:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
if ($conn->query($sqlContent) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sqlContent . "<br/>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: You need to separate the two queries or use [`mysqli::multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: @Jeto why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @dnFer Done. Didn't feel like elaborating, but I guess that should help a bit as is :)

Comment: Thank you @Jeto. This was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Every row must be enclosed in parantheses separately.
- You need to use single quotes (`'`), not backticks (`) for values.
- Also, you cannot have separate queries called inside `mysqli_query`. Use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for the same. From documentation:

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.

- Also, to prevent against [SQL injection related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602), please use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tsv` 
( `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`Id` text NOT NULL, `Date` text NOT NULL, 
`Quantity` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`_id`) ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=68 ; 

INSERT INTO `tsv` (`Id`,`Date`,`Quantity`) 
VALUES('1','2009-07-01','174'), 
      ('1','2009-07-02','96'),
      ('1','2009-07-03','271'), ... and so on
```

Comment: @JonasB happy to help :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to provide id. Id will auto increment while inserting data.

```
INSERT INTO tsv ('Date','Quantity') 
VALUES( '2009-07-01','174'), ('2009-07-02','96'), 
('2009-07-03','271'), ('2009-07-04','335'), 
('2009-07-06','72'), ('2009-07-07','246'), ('2009-07-08',
'93'), (,'2009-07-09','191'), ('2009-07-10','136'), 
('2009-07-11','200'), ('2009-07-13','151'), ('2009-07-15','99');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have several queries be part of the same `mysqli::query` call.

You need to separate the two queries or use [`mysqli::multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

[More on multiple statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).